# How to create authentication using next-auth with sequelize in next 13

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am working on latest next js and i want to create the authentication using next-auth with sequelize mysql database

**[...nextauth].ts**

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook"
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"
import TwitterProvider from "next-auth/providers/twitter"
import Auth0Provider from "next-auth/providers/auth0"

import SequelizeAdapter from "@auth/sequelize-adapter";
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
 

const sequelize = new Sequelize('db_user', 'db_user_pass', 'app_db', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'
});
 
// For more information on each option (and a full list of options) go to
// https://authjs.dev/reference/configuration/auth-config
export default NextAuth({
  // https://authjs.dev/reference/providers/
  providers: [],
  theme: {
    colorScheme: "dark",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token }) {
      token.userRole = "admin"
      return token
    },
  },
  adapter: SequelizeAdapter(sequelize),
});
```

I have tried the above one but not working and when i click sign in button it returns the [`error`](https://prnt.sc/ck3X7J6SsYEq)